# It now takes multiple C-g presses to cancel actions in minibuffer window

Tags: minibuffer, quitting

I'm a long time Emacs user.  For years it took a single `C-g` to cancel the operation in progress in the minibuffer.  For example:

`C-x b` to invoke switch to buffer
`C-g` to cancel
`C-x C-f` to visit file

In the past, this worked fine.  Now the single `C-g` seems to just start the "switch to buffer" again and issues an error message if you type `C-x C-f`.

This fails with an "emacs -Q".

I think now you have to hit two `C-g`'s to cancel.  It's driving me nuts.  When you've been using the same keystrokes for decades, it's tough to switch.

Google search leads to answers 5-7 years ago that implied it's a Gnome problem and suggested changing some Gnome setting that don't appear on my machine.

I'm running  GNU Emacs 26.3 from stock Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with gnome 3.36.8

UPDATE: summary of failed attempts to solve follow:

As C-] (abort-recursive-edit) gets the behavior I wanted, I figured
I'd just remap the C-g the abort-recursive-edit

These failed.  C-h b  was used to confirm any keymappings:

- (global-set-key "\C-g" 'abort-recursive-edit )
- (global-set-key [remap keyboard-quit] #'keyboard-quit-context+) and corresponding *.el file. Per mmmmmmm See https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ffbser/withemacs_quit_current_context/
- (global-set-key [remap keyboard-quit] #'abort-recursive-edit)
- (require 'bind-key) ; (bind-key "C-g" 'abort-recursive-edit') from the use-package library. https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#binding-within-local-keymaps

I'm only stumbling about the mock lisp (see I don't even know what it's called).  emacs must be special casing C-g somehow and implementing it before the key map.  When I map the key to abort-recurse-edit it still behaves as if keyboard-quit was typed.

I think one of the above attempts mapped the keyboard-quit function to  abort-recursive-edit

A POSITIVE CLUE:

It's GNOME as Fran Burstall suggested.

- ssh localhost
- emacs

Works as desired in terminal mode

Haven't had time to chase it down, but I'll post here when I do.

Comment: I think you meant `C-x C-f`, not `C-x f`. In Emacs 20, it takes a single `C-g` to abort `C-x C-f`. The same is true in the latest Emacs release (27.2), and all prior releases. And the same is true for `C-x b`. Please describe things wrt vanilla Emacs, `emacs -Q` (no init file). Otherwise, you need to specify just what you're loading and how it changes the vanilla behavior.

Comment: emacs -Q behaves the same way. C-] and ESC ESC ESC implement the desired behavior.  Any thoughts on side effects from key mapping C-g to whatever C-] is bound to?

Comment: The Gnome Human Interface Guidelines suggest the C-g is bound to "find next" by the desktop environment.  Maybe search in the Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcuts so see if that is the case?

Comment: You say "now".  What (else) has changed between 'then' and "now".  (Were you also using "GNU Emacs 26.3 from stock Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with gnome 3.36.8" 'then', for instance?)

Comment: I have had this issue going back many years - possibly even Emacs 19 - C-g is often not sufficient - I now have bound the function here to a key https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ffbser/withemacs_quit_current_context/

Comment: Provided updates to failed solution attempts in original msg.